# *Why* are eigenvectors the principal components in Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, pca, eigenvalues

I am confused as to why eigenvalues are the principal components. What is the intuition behind finding the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix for PCA?

[image: PCA]